# xslt: Generate xml attribute value with single quotation (apostrophe) as delimiter

Tags: xml, xslt, delimiter, apostrophe

xslt processing seems always to generate attribute values with double quotation marks as delimiter.
Input xml:

```
<a b='"c"' />
```

Output xml:

```
<a b="&quot;c&quot;"/>
```

I have to generate XML files with apostrophe as attribute value delimiter for a phone device.
This device only accept attribute values with apostrophe and double quotation marks as delimiter. 
E.g.:

```
<SYMB_ITEM ID="BS_Accounts.astAccounts[0].aucAccountName[0]"
class="symb_item" value='"test_3"'/>
```

Is it possible to keep apostrophe as delimiter for attribute values with xslt (xlstproc)?

Comment: i thought of `CDATA` and something like `disable-output-escaping`, bus is this valid xml what you want to generate?

Comment: I think so. http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/ Literal data is any quoted string not containing the quotation mark used as a delimiter for that string. Literals are used for specifying the content of internal entities (EntityValue), the values of attributes (AttValue), and external identifiers (SystemLiteral). Note that a SystemLiteral can be parsed without scanning for markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly: would setting output to "text" help?

```
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" indent="no"/>
```

Example XSLT sheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" indent="no"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="a">
    &lt;a b='<xsl:value-of select="@b"/>'&gt;
  </xsl:template>                      
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For following XML file:

```
<xml>
  <a b='"c"' />   
  <a b='"x"' />
</xml>
```

Produces (as I think) desired effect:

```
<a b='"c"'>
<a b='"x"'>
```

Comment: OK thanks this would work. Even if the xsl would get little more complex.